# Capturar elemento mediante etiqueta name en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función en javascript que captura un elemento por su etiqueta id.

```
appendTo: "#crearviaje",
```

Necesitaría poder capturar ese elemento mediante su etiqueta name y no soy capaz de encontrar la forma de hacerlo.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Un saludo,

Answer (score 1):

Puede usar la funcion getElementsByName, sin embargo esta devuelve un arreglo, dado que puede haber varios elementos con el mismo nombre.

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("NAME");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    alert(''+x[i]);
  }
}
```

Si tiene la certeza de que solo hay un elemento con ese nombre puede referirse a él como: 
x[0].

Sin necesidad de iterar.

Comment: He intentado usar esa manera pero después no soy capaz de usar la variable creada ( en este caso x) en la linea de código 'appendTo: "#crearviaje",'